Shortcut for "run cell" for Jupyter Lab on MacBook
I'm using JupyterLab on a MacBook. For some reason, the default keyboard shortcut for running a cell is "Control + Enter", but I want to change it to "Command + Enter". I found a helpful article and tried to overwrite the shortcut by adding the following command:
{"shortcuts":
    [
        {
            "command": "notebook:run-cell",
            "keys": [
                "Command Enter"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        }
    ]
}

like the image below:

However, even after re-opening Jupyter Lab, the shortcut doesn't take effect. Why not?

The problem was resolved. I was overwriting the shortcut only for the ".jp-Notebook:focus" selector. I also needed to overwrite it for the ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode" selector as well.
{"shortcuts": 
    [
        {
            "command": "notebook:run-cell",
            "keys": [
                "Cmd Enter"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        }, 
        {
            "command": "notebook:run-cell",
            "keys": [
                "Cmd Enter"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode"
        }, 
    ]
}

After saving this shortcut, I can use run the selected cell by Cmd + Enter on MacBook.
